# stop localhost from appearing in email headers

Tags: email, sendmail

I am trying to configure sendmail on a Linux Server, so that localhost is not mentioned in the email headers.

I've set the server hostname in /etc/sysconfig/network, and edited the line
Djmydomain.com in my sendmail.cf file (and restarted everything).

But still the email headers have this:

```
Received: by x.x.x.x with SMTP id xxx;
        Sat, 5 Nov 2011 13:48:43 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by x.x.x.x with SMTP id xxx;
        Sat, 05 Nov 2011 13:48:41 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <root@mydomain.com>
Received: from mydomain.com ([x.x.x.x])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id xxx
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Sat, 05 Nov 2011 13:48:41 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: x.x.x.x is neither permitted 
nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@mydomain.com) client-ip=x.x.x.x;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: x.x.x.x is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@mydomain.com) smtp.mail=root@mydomain.com
Received: from mydomain.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by mydomain.com (...) with ESMTP id xxx
    for <me@myemailaddress.com>; Sat, 5 Nov 2011 20:48:44 GMT
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by mydomain.com (...) id xxx
    for me@myemailaddress.com; Sat, 5 Nov 2011 20:48:44 GMT
Date: Sat, 5 Nov 2011 20:48:44 GMT
From: root <root@mydomain.com>
Message-Id: <XXX>
```

I don't think the references to localhost.localdomain and localhost should be there - am concerned about the domain getting blacklisted etc.

Can anyone tell me how to remove them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fix Fully Qualified Host Name reported by the command below

```
hostname --fqdn
```

It is OS/Distribution specific.

**OR**

Force sendmail use another "this host" name as described in cf/README file

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/whoami.html